# Show that $\langle{x,y\,\vert\,x^{2}y^{-2}}\rangle$ is not isomorphic to $S_{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

Could someone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

Show that $\langle{x,y\,\vert\,x^{2}y^{-2}}\rangle$ is not isomorphic to $S_{3}$

Comment: There are groups bigger than $S_3$ with more than one involution.

Comment: This seems similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2470120

Comment: Take the quotient of that group by $xy^{-1}$. The group becomes $\mathbb{Z}$, which is infinite.

Comment: Your group is definitely not finite.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997108/how-do-you-know-which-relations-will-define-a-group) for general guidelines on how to show a group given by generators and relations is not isomorphic to a given group.

Comment: You have asked many questions already of the same sort. I suggest you stop asking questions here and think about them much, much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_3$ is a finite group of order 6, so any group element $g\in S_3$ satisfies $g^6 = 1$.

Can you see why $x^6 \neq 1$ in the group $\langle x, y \;|\; x^2y^{-2}\rangle$?